# javascript array with some elements that are keyed

Tags: javascript

I noticed that the return value from regex `matchAll()` is rather peculiar. As an example: `['test1', 'e', 'st1', '1', index: 0, input: 'test1test2', length: 4]`, where first few elements could be referenced by indices and the rest could be referenced by names. Is this still an `Array` and how can I create one myself?

Comment: You ask a question that you have not even checked yourself.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get from a regex `.exec` command is indeed an array, but it also has a few non-standard properties assigned to it:

```js
const re = /fo(o)/;
const str = ' foo bar';
const match = re.exec(str);

// Look at the result in the browser console, not the snippet console:
console.log(match);
```

```js
const re = /fo(o)/;
const str = ' foo bar';
const match = re.exec(str);

// Yes, it's still an array:
console.log(Array.isArray(match));
```

Result:

```
0: "foo"
1: "o"
groups: undefined
index: 1
input: " foo bar"
length: 2
```

You can achieve this same effect by assigning to properties of an array as if the array was an object (which it is, technically):

```js
const arr = ['foo', 'o'];
arr.groups = undefined;
arr.index = 1;
arr.input = " foo bar";

// Look at the result in the browser console, not the snippet console:
console.log(arr);
```

In almost all other situations, having or assigning arbitrary non-integer properties of an array is a *very strange* thing to do (and not something one should see in clean code).